# docker compose django and node

Tags: node.js, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to make an application in django via docker and I want separate the backend (django) container from frontend (node, react) container using only one repository.

I want to run node commands from django container (for example: npm init and creating the package.json at main folder).

Is it a good pratice?

If yes, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the points for containers is that you build each technology in its own container. Why do you feel you need to use the same container?

Comment: And are you using node just to build static files? Or as an actual server?

Comment: I do not feel that i need to use the same container, i feel that i need to use two containers and one repository for my code. I going to use node just for build static files (use webpack)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need Nodejs for building, you should have one docker image just for building (and if you want, deploying) the static files, and then use a whole different docker setup for the actual production environment.

You can look at https://github.com/dkarchmer/django-aws-template (disclaimer, I am the developer) to see an example. Unfortunately, the project is not yet fully tested and documented, but shows how I propose to handle static files outside Django (it does emulate what I do for real in production - just not fully tested).

You will see a top level docker image I use only for building the webpack type project (using gulp), and actually releasing that directly to S3. The top level index.html file gets copied to the django templates directory, to be used as the base template by other django templates (you may not need this if your front-end will be 100% independent of Django). But IMO, I find it useful to mix. For example, I do all the authentication portion using regular django (django-allauth).

Your question is fairly open ended (not exactly a good way to ask in SO), but I hope the link above gives you some ideas on how to implemented what you need.

Comment: This project does not have a container for each technology. One container for django, one for nginx, one for node, one for database and another for data. My question was about link the container django with the container node

Comment: But you said that it is ok to use one container for building static files. You also ask about best practices. Using one container is the wrong thing to do. I am not sure you are explaining what you want well. But my bad for incorrectly interpreting.